# Match a sequence unless it is preceded by another sequence with regex (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm aware that Javascript has no lookbehind feature and although there are ways around it, none of them seem to help.

I need to match any sequence of characters, unless it is preceded by a certain sequence and succeeded by another sequence.

So, with a sentence like:

`The watchdoggy jumped up.`

If I want to match all letters unless they are preceded by `watch` and succeeded by `gy` it should return `The jumped up.`

The trick here is to do this in Javascript, though. Any ideas?

Comment: Just one match, or repeated matches across a string?

Comment: How would you do this if javascript had lookbehind?

Comment: is it ok if you match just the letters which are preceded by `watch` and succeeded by `gy` and replace with empty string?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do this in a single location, two capture groups would do it.

As a replacement operation:

```js
var rex = /^(.*?)(?:watch.*?gy ?)(.*?)$/;
var str = "The watchdoggy jumped up.";
var result = str.replace(rex, "$1$2");
snippet.log("Result with match: '" + result + "'");
result = "Test that not matching works correctly".replace(rex, "$1$2");
snippet.log("Result without match: '" + result + "'");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

As just a match and re-assemble:

```js
var str = "The watchdoggy jumped up.";
var m = /^(.*?)(?:watch.*?gy ?)(.*?)$/.exec(str);
var result;
if (!m) {
  // No match, take the whole string
  result = str;
} else {
  // Match, take just the groups
  result = m[1] + m[2];
}
snippet.log("Result: '" + result + "'");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: The non-capturing group should be optional, though.

Comment: @Bergi: No need, and it complicates things.

Comment: But then it wouldn't match anything if there is no `watchdoggy` in the input (while it should match the whole input)?

Comment: @Bergi: That's fine, see above. (Too bad the OP's done an ask-and-run. Until/unless they show up again, I'm moving on.)

Comment: Ah, you're working around that case with the if construct. I see.

Comment: This works great thanks. It's a complex problem and I've been unable to reframe it more simply. Thanks again!

Comment: @Bergi: Or with the `replace`, which is my preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if you have more than one locations:

```
\b(?!watch(.*?)gy\b)\w+    //if you want to capture only words (\w)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tH3nP2/2)

More generic one:

```
(\b(?!watch(.*?)gy\b).*?\b)+   //captures everything except letters
                              // preceeded by 'watch' and succeeded by 'gy'
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tH3nP2/3)